# Merge Sort with Compare Function - Core Dumped

Tags: c, mergesort, coredump

Hi I am running a merge short with a compare function which is causing a core dumped fault with the following error:

```
part1 21 shortbooks.txt
*** glibc detected *** part1: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0867b258 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x409fb6]
part1[0x80489c6]
part1[0x80487fb]
part1[0x80487fb]
part1[0x80487fb]
part1[0x8048ac9]
part1[0x8048d41]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x3b1e36]
part1[0x8048561]
======= Memory map: ========
00376000-00393000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1311353    /lib/ld-2.13.so
00393000-00394000 r--p 0001c000 fd:00 1311353    /lib/ld-2.13.so
00394000-00395000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 1311353    /lib/ld-2.13.so
0039b000-0051e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1311360    /lib/libc-2.13.so
0051e000-0051f000 ---p 00183000 fd:00 1311360    /lib/libc-2.13.so
0051f000-00521000 r--p 00183000 fd:00 1311360    /lib/libc-2.13.so
00521000-00522000 rw-p 00185000 fd:00 1311360    /lib/libc-2.13.so
00522000-00525000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
00577000-00593000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1345987    /lib/libgcc_s-4.5.1-20100924.so.1
00593000-00594000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 1345987    /lib/libgcc_s-4.5.1-20100924.so.1
008e6000-008e7000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:19 435651043  /home/S10/rowlanj0/COMP26120/ex7/part1
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00001000 00:19 435651043  /home/S10/rowlanj0/COMP26120/ex7/part1
0867b000-0869c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b783b000-b783c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b7867000-b7868000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
bfb25000-bfb49000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is anyone able to advise on what might be causing this fault and how to solve it?

```
void memcopy(B *to, B *from, int count ) {

  while ( count-- > 0 ) *to++ = *from++ ;

}

void merge_sort(B* book, int n, int elementsize, int (*p_cmp_f)( ) )  {

B *firsthalf, *endoffirsthalf, *secondhalf, *endofsecondhalf, *resultbuffer, *p_result;

int halfsize ;

if (n <= 1 ) return ;

halfsize = n / 2 ;

firsthalf = book ;

secondhalf = book + halfsize * elementsize ;

merge_sort( firsthalf, halfsize, elementsize, p_cmp_f ) ;
merge_sort( secondhalf, n - halfsize, elementsize, p_cmp_f ) ;

endoffirsthalf = secondhalf ;

endofsecondhalf = book + n * elementsize ;

resultbuffer = (B*) malloc( n * elementsize ) ;

p_result = resultbuffer ;

while( firsthalf < endoffirsthalf && secondhalf < endofsecondhalf ) {

  if( (*p_cmp_f)( firsthalf, secondhalf ) < 0 ) {

    memcopy( p_result, firsthalf, elementsize ) ;
    firsthalf += elementsize ;

  }

  else {

    memcopy( p_result, secondhalf, elementsize ) ;
    secondhalf += elementsize ;

  }

  p_result += elementsize ;

}

while( firsthalf < endoffirsthalf ) {

  memcopy( p_result, firsthalf, elementsize ) ;
  firsthalf += elementsize ;
  p_result += elementsize ;

}

while( secondhalf < endofsecondhalf ) {

  memcopy( p_result, secondhalf, elementsize ) ;
  secondhalf += elementsize ;
  p_result += elementsize ;

}

  memcopy( book, resultbuffer, n * elementsize ) ;

  free(resultbuffer) ;

}
```

Here is the code as requested.

Here is the struct and one of the compare functions:

```
 typedef struct book{
 double rating;
 double price;
 double relevance;
 int ID;
 }B;
```

and the compare function:

```
int comp_on_price(const void *a, const void *b)
{

if ((*(B *)a).price < (*(B *)b).price)
  return 1;
else if ((*(B *)a).price > (*(B *)b).price)
  return -1;
else
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you tried to `free()` a pointer you didn't `malloc()`. Some code would help.

Comment: If you compile with -g and run the application from gdb, and type "backtrace" after it crashes, you can get more information

Comment: How are we supposed to help if you didn't post the code?

Comment: Funny ... - the same use case in 15min ... homework?

Comment: Try to run the program in valgrind

Comment: Where do you define "B"?

Comment: what about the compare function?

Comment: there are the compare and struct def's

Comment: Your pointer arithmetic doesn't look right. You either work with `char*` and multiply everything by `elementsize`, or work with `B*` and replace all `elementsize` with 1.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your program is corrupting internal heap data structures. This can be a difficult problem to track down since the problem may not be detected until long after the corruption occurs.

Some common causes are:

- Freeing a pointer twice
- Freeing a pointer that wasn't allocated with malloc
- Buffer overflow: writing data off either end of a buffer allocated with malloc.

I don't know if this is the root cause of your problem, but I did notice some mistakes in pointer arithmetic.

```
secondhalf = book + halfsize * elementsize ;
```

In the example below, you don't need to multiply by `elementsize`. The compiler will do this automatically when adding an integer and a pointer; it will assume `elementsize == sizeof(B)`. If this assumption is not valid, cast `book` to `(char*)` before doing the addition (with multiplication). This will always work since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.

If your program is small you could try using Valgrind to track down any problems. Valgrind is going at finding memory problems, such as heap corruption, leaks, and uses of undefined variables. It is very slow though, so it won't work for programs which run for a long time.